# Image crop Code in Symfony 3.3 works in localhost well but does not work in live website

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony-3.3

So I recently saw a tutorial and created an Image crop and upload feature in website. In my case I have :-

```
  a. Title
  b. Description
  c. Image
  d. Date
```

Initially I did exactly like in tutorial when file browse is clicked the image would have mounted in Bootstrap 4 modal where there had a feature to crop. The main problem over there was when I clicked on that crop button the ajax used to run and persist all the data into database. Later I changed in JavaScript so that when crop button is clicked the cropped image is displayed and finally the Submit button would saved all data in database. This feature is working well in Localhost, but when I updated in my live website the features seems not to work.

JavaScript Code:

```
 $('.crop_image').click(function(event){
$image_crop.croppie('result', {
  type: 'canvas',
  size: 'viewport'

}).then(function(response){
    $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
    $("#previewImg").attr('src', response);
    getResponse = response;
});

$('#upload_btn').on('click',function(){


            var block = getResponse.split(";");
            // Get the content type
            var contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];// In this case "image/gif"
            // get the real base64 content of the file
            var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];// In this case "iVBORw0KGg...."

            // Convert to blob
            var blob = b64toBlob(realData, contentType);

            let formData = new FormData(form);
            formData.append('image_path', blob);
            $.ajax({

            url: "{{ path('app_bundle_route') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'},
            success:  function(data){


                $("#previewImg").attr('src', getResponse);
            }
          });
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @Route("/form", name="form")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $members = new members();
    $form = $this->createForm(event::class, $members);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            return $this->redirectToRoute('dev');
    }
    return $this->render('admin/create.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
* @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
* @Route("/getImage", name="getImage")
* @Method({"POST"})
*/

public function getImageAction(Request $request){

            $members = new members();
              $form = $this->createForm(event::class, $members);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){


                if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
                  /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
                $file = $request->files->get('image_path');
                //$file = $form->get('image_path');



                $filename = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

                $file->move($this->getParameter('event_directory'), $filename);

                $title = $form['title']->getData();
                $description = $form['description']->getData();
                $date = $form['date']->getData();

                $members->setImagePath($filename);
                $members->setTitle($title);
                $members->setDescription($description);
                $members->setDate($date);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($members);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash(
                        'notice', 'Event Added!!'
                );
            }                
        }
        return new JsonResponse("This is Ajax");
 }
```

I have deleted cache several times but didn't work. The exact code works in Localhost.

Comment: Probably some package is not installed. Check whether the php-gd is installed in server. Install php-gd using command sudo apt-get install php-gd to install the package. Check log in the server. I may shows the error occurred.

Comment: I dont htink this line gonna work `            url: "{{ path('app_bundle_route') }}",` you need to use FOSJSRouting

Comment: Ahmed the url is fine. As I said the ajax was saving data before but after I changed to on click the issue happened there. In Localhost it is OK but in live site the code is not giving any effect. But anyway I'll try FOSJs as well. Let see..